# Chilkat - CFtp2 - Java - Login failure when credential(username/password) is in Japanese/Korean/Arabic

Tags: java, ftp, chilkat

When I am trying to login in my FTP server using Japanese/Korean/Arabic username/password through my CkFtp2.java client it is failing with message "530 Please log in with USER and PASS first." Every thing is going fine when I am using English username/password. Both credential is created following same steps and in same ftps server.I am able to login via FileZilla client using all languages credential.

Steps to reproduce:
1) Installed FileZilla server.
2) Create a user with username/password in Japanese.You can create one more of English.
3) Through FileZilla client you will be able to login and can see list directory of the server using both type of user.
4) Now write a simple java program using Chilkat provided interface CkFtp2.java.
5) Provide hostname, port, username/password and other required details.
6) You will be able to login with English credential but it will fail with Japanese credential when you try to perform some operation like getting file count or changing directory.

Thanks in advance for your input, let me know if you need more info to debug it.

Comment: Make sure your client library is sending the credentials in encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Verified, I am able to print my credential back in console. In log also getting replyLineQP: 202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed.  A pre-release of Chilkat v9.5.0.83 can be provided for those interested.